# How to convert a bash function definition into a markdown fenced block by sed, awk or perl

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, markdown

I have a bunch of bash functions which I would like to convert into markdown code blocks. For example, one of them looks like: (There may are some nested curly brackets and blank lines inside the function)

```
upr()
{
    for chr; do
       case $chr in
         [a-z]*) chr_opts="-n" nxt -32 "$chr" ;;
         *) printf "%c${sep}" "$chr" 2>/dev/null ;;
       esac
    done
}
```

I want to change it like this:

````
```bash
upr()
{
    for chr; do
       case $chr in
         [a-z]*) chr_opts="-n" nxt -32 "$chr" ;;
         *) printf "%c${sep}" "$chr" 2>/dev/null ;;
       esac
    done
}
```
````

My thought is to put the function definition (treated as a paragraph) into sed hold space and add the markdown marks. How can I do this with sed, awk or perl, or any whatever methods?

Comment: ```type upr``` shows the function and its lines of code. I guess you could make use of it to surround the output with the markdown lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this question is too broad to be on-topic. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: Could you show the attempted Sed script, even if it doesn't quite work yet? Can you make assumptions about the layout of your Bash functions, for example that they all use braces `{…}` and that the closing brace will always be on a line of its own and that it won't have any indentation?

Comment: Dear all, a little explanation about my question: I have a large mardown file with dozens of bash functions inside.  I seek any sed/awk/perl/bash codes to convert these function definitions into markdown code blocks.  @ufopilot's awk code fulfils this purpose perfectly. Anyway thank you all for the response of my questions.

Comment: You should include non-trivial cases in your sample input/output, e.g. functions that include array initialization like `arr=()` or comments like `# call foo() next` so you and we have those cases to test with. It's always easy to match what you want but harder to not match what you don't want and so including cases of similar-looking text that you don't want to match is important in an example. Also, if you want to process multiple of anything (functions in this case) then make sure to include at least 2 of them in your example so we can see what separates them.

Answer (score 1):

For multiline functions

```
funcname()
{
....
}
```

---

````
$ awk '/\(\)/{print "```bash"}{ print }/^}$/{print "```"}' input_file

```bash
upr()
{
    for chr; do
       case $chr in
         [a-z]*) chr_opts="-n" nxt -32 "$chr" ;;
         *) printf "%c${sep}" "$chr" 2>/dev/null ;;
       esac
    done
}
```

```bash
func2()
{
   foo="bar"
   while :; do
     echo ${#foo}
     sleep 5
   done
}
```

```bash
func3()
{
   foo=2 bar=1
   echo "${foo}" "$bar"
}
```
````

Save changes inplace

````
$ awk -i inplace '/\(\)/{printf "```bash\n"}{ print }/^}$/{print "```"}' input_file
````

Answer (score 1):

With `declare -fp func`?

````
$ myFuncs=( foo bar qux )
$ for f in "${myFuncs[@]}"; do
    printf '```bash\n'; declare -fp "$f"; printf '```\n\n'
  done
```bash
foo () 
{ 
    echo "I am function foo"
}
```

```bash
bar () 
{ 
    echo "I am function bar"
}
```

```bash
qux () 
{ 
    echo "I am function qux"
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed -e '/^\S\+\s*()/!b;i\```bash' -e ':a;n;/^}/!ba;a\```' file
````

Insert   ```` ``` bash ```` before the function and append ```` ``` ```` after it.

Comment: Dear @potong, it works and many thanks.  I would like to see more general situations. For example, there are some white spaces at head of  closing curly bracket; there are nested curly brackets cross multiple lines; etc. Any solutions are welcome.